# Unable to get data from created() to data() in VueJS 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am fetching data from API inside the created method and i want to use these data in the page.

Here is my code.

```
created(){
    let id = this.$route.params.id
    let videos;
    this.$axios.get(this.$axios.defaults.apiURL + 'v1.0.0/tips/' +id,).then((response) => {
      this.videos = response.data.data;


    }, (error) => {
      toast.$toast.error('Something went wrong! Please try again', {
        position: 'top'
      })
    });
  },
  data(){
    let videos = this.videos;
    return {
      video: {
        sources: [{
          src: videos.video_url,
          type: 'video/mp4'
        }],
        options: {
          autoplay: true,
          volume: 0.6,
          poster: videos.thumbnail
        }
      }

    }
  }
```

I am getting error that thumbnail and video_url is not defined. This 2 values are coming from API response. How can i solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two obvious issues with your code (without seeing it in action):

- `created` is a [synchronous hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created), but your axios request is returning a promise. Instead of waiting for the promise, you are immediately trying to show the result, hence the issue you are encountering - the data just hasn't arrived yet.
- Your use of `this` seems a bit chaotic (i.e. `let videos = this.videos` - [where would `this.videos` come from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)? The only other 'videos' is [declared inside of a different function with `let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let))

There are multiple ways to solve this, depending on what you want to show while you are fetching the data and what type of component this is - if you want to show a spinner while you are waiting for the request to be answered, or if you just want to show some progress bar on the previous page and only enter this one once it's loaded.

**In-component loading**

In the first case, I would suggest setting a variable or using a loader management solution like [vue-wait](https://github.com/f/vue-wait). Your code could look like this then:

```js
data() {
    return {
      loading: true,
      videos: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    video() {
      return this.videos ? {
        sources: [{
          src: this.videos.video_url,
          type: 'video/mp4'
        }],
        options: {
          autoplay: true,
          volume: 0.6,
          poster: this.videos.thumbnail
        }
      } : null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fetch() {
      let id = this.$route.params.id
      this.$axios.get(this.$axios.defaults.apiURL + 'v1.0.0/tips/' + id, ).then((response) => {
        this.videos = response.data.data;
      }, (error) => {
        toast.$toast.error('Something went wrong! Please try again', {
          position: 'top'
        })
      }).finally(() => (this.loading = false));
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.fetch()
  },
```

In your template, you would add somewhere `v-if=!loading` to make sure that the request has finished before you try to show something

**Data-fetching before entering page**

If this is a page though, you could request the data in beforeRouteEnter - there's a whole article that explains the principle on the [vue site](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html)